# mysql column (timestamp) is also automatically updated with system current time

Tags: mysql

how come when i update one column but another column (timestamp) is also automatically updated with system current time

database mysql:

example sql statement which i excuted

```
select id, processstatus, processtimestamp from mytable where id=229;

id        processstatus                                                                                        processtimestamp          
--------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------- 
229       EXPORT_FILEA.txt                                                                                     2015-11-04 12:54:49.0  





update  mytable set processstatus='EXPORT_TO_FILE_B' where id=229;

select id, processstatus, processtimestamp from mytable where id=229;

id        processstatus                                                                                        processtimestamp          
--------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------- 
229       EXPORT_TO_FILE_B                                                                                     2015-11-04 13:09:41.0
```

Comment: you want that column to be updated or not?

Comment: i dont want the column (processtimestamp) be automatically updated. this column should not be automatically updated with current_timestamp as well because it is not created as not null default current_timestamp; it is only created as not null

Comment: try @Rahautos 2nd query

Answer (score 0):

you can create `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`  column like that :-

```
ALTER TABLE `table`  ADD `col_name` DATETIME 
on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  ;
```

Try this query :-

```
ALTER TABLE `table` CHANGE `col_name` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

> Remove `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`